# restrict website link to specific geolocation

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, geofencing

I am developing an web application where I want to restrict the use of particular link of my website to specific geolocation. eg. if I am near 30 mtr radius from a particular geolocation point 'A' then only i can access that link other it should pop "You are Far". 
Is there any way to do this. It could be kind of geofencing. 
Can anyone please suggest some solution to do this? is there any Google API available to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators#directive-decorator-example), suggest a way of decorating AngularJS directives, You can easily replace directive compile function with your own version and inside that version of yours, do your calculations or whatever you want and set the `tElem`'s `innerHTML` with what you want and also change the `href` attribute. In your case you need to decorate the `a` tag !

Hope it helps.